# How to detect windows 11 from user agent?

Tags: web, browser, user-agent

How I can figure out if someone opens my website in windows 11?

I test user agent and when someone opens my website with windows 11 I will get this

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"

So technically this says it's windows 10, not 11.

Is there any way to detect this?

Comment: And now you see just one of the reasons  why you cannot and should not rely on the user agent string to be a reliable source for such information.

Comment: @Rob still you need this for analytics website

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the **User-Agent** string to detect the browser and operating system is not reliable and is a legacy practice. You won't be able to detect **Windows 11** because **Windows 11** will use "Window NT 10.0" which is the same that **Windows 10** uses.

But you can use User-Agent client hints in new browsers like Edge 94+ and Chrome 95+.

For **Windows 11**, look for these request headers:

```
Sec-CH-UA-Platform set to 'Windows'
Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version set to 13.0.0 and above
```

See this link for more information: [Detecting Windows 11 using User-Agent Client Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/how-to-detect-win11)

Comment: So if its a legacy, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Well, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1693295 capped the Windows version at 10 for Firefox, so that's really not going to work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Works only on Edge browswer as far as I can tell. Adding the response header "Accept-CH:Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version"
returns
[Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform-Version] => "14.0.0"

...but this is not supplied by Chrome or Firefox.

AFAIK you can't detect Windows 11 except with Edge.